# partitioned hard drive

Tags: windows-xp

I am unable to extend that partition on my C drive, and have 0 disk space left to get a partition program.  I have 38gb unallocated on the drive.  I tried expanding in disk manager but it does not exist when I right click on the drive.  any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Boot from a GParted Live Cd: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

It will be able to resize any partition type that you're likely to be using on XP.